# How to correctly include fonts in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

Currently fonts are included in CSS file like below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url("../fonts/icomoon.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/icomoon.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/icomoon.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
```

But when the page loads, it blocks rendering until these heavy fonts are loaded. Should I just include in HTML using `<style>` tag but is there a better way to keep page loading speed optimized?

Comment: Load the CSS at the end of the page.

Comment: you can try lazy loading of fonts if they are heavy. more info can be found here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/webfont-optimization

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use JavaScript it will be the same ... instead you can show a preloader overlay until the page loads completely .. then just hide the preloader overlay

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/